# Exporting as a pdf truncates axes labels

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

Given two example plots generated with:

```
p1=ListLogPlot[{{{20, 5}, {400, 0.5}, {750, 0.005}}}, Joined -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \(min\)]\) [km/s]", 
   "\[Eta](\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \(min\)]\)) \
[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(-3\)]\) (km/s\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\
\), \(-1\)]\)]"}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> 
  Directive[Thickness[0.003], FontSize -> 25, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
 GridLines -> {{200, 400, 600, 800}, {0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], LabelStyle -> Directive[14],
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 800}, {5 10^-4, 10.}}, ImageSize -> {600, 400}]
```

I attempt to combine the two images in a row with `GraphicsGrid` as follows:

```
panelPlot = 
 Show[GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}}, ImageSize -> 1250, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}]]
```

And then I export the plots as a pdf file using:

```
Export["plot.pdf", panelPlot]
```

The exponents of the axis labels get cut off, as seen here:
[image]

I have tried `ImagePadding`, `ImageMargins`, and changing the `ImageSize` and resolutions and nothing seems to work.

Is there any way to fix this issue with pdf export?

Comment: Can you try to make your question self contained and include everything needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Nasser Yes I have added code with mock data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Exporting the images individually resolves this issue. So it seems to be a problem with GraphicsGrid itself.

Comment: Which version are you using? In ``12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 24, 2021)``, everything [seems ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGZE2.png). You can try with ``Show[..., ImageMargins->20]``.

Comment: @Domen It is version 12.1 on MacOS. ImagieMargins in Show does not resolve the issue unfortunately. I tried with ImagePadding as well with different options and this did not work either.

Comment: For individual images `p1, p2`, use: `ImagePadding -> {{100, 30}, {100, 30}}` and `panelPlot = 
 GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}}, ImageSize -> 1250, Spacings -> {-30, 0}]`. There is no need for `Show`.

Comment: @Syed changing 100->150 and removing Show worked for me! If you'd like to make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I am glad, I was able to help you. Take care.